# Show the convergence of the sequence $\{a^k\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, vectors

> **Task**: Show the convergence of sequence $\{a^k\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, where
>   $$a_k=\begin{pmatrix}a^k_1\\a_2^k\\a^3_k\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^3$$ with $a_1^k=\left(\frac{k}{k+2}\right)^k$, $a_2^k=\left(k-\sqrt{k^2-1}\right)^k$, $a_3^k=k\sin\frac{1}{k}$.

**Question**:
Do I just need to show that every $a_i^k$ for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$ is convergent in order to show that $a_k$ is convergent? I would just compute the limits like that:
\begin{align}
a_1=\left(\frac{k}{k+2}\right)^k=\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{k}}\right)^k=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{2}{k}\right)^k}\overbrace{\to}^{k\to\infty}e^{-2}\in\mathbb{R}
\end{align}

etc. and then I would come to the conclusion that all of the $a_i$'s are convergent so is $a_k$. Is this correct?

**Edit**: How can I calculate $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_2^k$? I've got to $$\exp\left\{\lim_{k\to\infty}k\cdot \lim_{k\to\infty} \ln \frac{1}{k+\sqrt{k^2-1}}\right\}$$ but my solution is, that this equals $e^0=1$ which is not true, according to Wolfram Alpha. Can you help me?

Comment: This would work. If each component sequence converges, the vector sequence converges as well...

Comment: Alright, thanks for the fast answer. One more question regarding a task in my lecture: $a_k$ does not converge if $a_k\in\mathbb{Q}^3$, because $e^{-2}\notin \mathbb{Q}$, right?

Comment: Yes. It is Cauchy but does not converge to a rational.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I've edited my question, because I have a problem calculating $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_2^k$.